# Problem with table of contents after page resize

Tags: c#, aspose, aspose.words

I have doc and change page size

```
builder.PageSetup.PageWidth = ConvertUtil.MillimeterToPoint(219.1);
builder.PageSetup.PageHeight = ConvertUtil.MillimeterToPoint(285.7);
```

Doc has Table of content, but after changed size it placed wrong
[wrong sized TOC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6k1P.png)

Any suggestions how to place normal TOC full page width?

Tried with different docs. Same problem.

Comment: Problem at tabStops

Answer (score 0):

Width of the TOC is defined by tab stops in the TOC styles. So, after increasing width of the page, you have also increase size of the TOC styles tab stops accordingly. Please see the following code:

```cs
Document doc = new Document(@"C:\Temp\in.docx");
doc.FirstSection.PageSetup.PageWidth = doc.FirstSection.PageSetup.PageWidth + 200;
UpdateTocStyles(doc);
// Update fields to rebuild the TOC.
doc.UpdateFields();
doc.Save(@"C:\Temp\out.docx");
```

---

```cs
private void UpdateTocStyles(Document doc)
{
    // List of all TOC styles.
    StyleIdentifier[] tocStyles = new StyleIdentifier[]
    {
        StyleIdentifier.Toc1,
        StyleIdentifier.Toc2,
        StyleIdentifier.Toc3,
        StyleIdentifier.Toc4,
        StyleIdentifier.Toc5,
        StyleIdentifier.Toc6,
        StyleIdentifier.Toc7,
        StyleIdentifier.Toc8,
        StyleIdentifier.Toc9
    };

    // Calculate width of the page without left and right margins.
    double pageWidth = doc.FirstSection.PageSetup.PageWidth - doc.FirstSection.PageSetup.RightMargin - doc.FirstSection.PageSetup.LeftMargin;
    // Reset tab stops in TOC styles.
    foreach (StyleIdentifier tocStyleIdentifier in tocStyles)
    {
        Style tocStyle = doc.Styles[tocStyleIdentifier];
        tocStyle.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Clear();
        tocStyle.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Add(new TabStop(pageWidth, TabAlignment.Right, TabLeader.Dots));
    }

}
```

Comment: You are God of Aspose !